# Bash alias to wrap around Git commit

Tags: bash, git, alias

I am trying to write a bash alias to wrap around a Git commit command.

Here is what my typical Git commit looks like.
`git commit -am 'Comments in here'`

Here is what I have attempted to write as an alias (which would go inside my .bashrc file), so I don't have to write out the whole command every time.

`comm(){
    git commit -am $1
}`

Then I would call it like this: `comm 'Comments in here'`

However I keep getting this error: `fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.`

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: To prevent the shell from treating `$1` as multiple words, you will need to quote it (`git commit -am "$1"`). That said, I recommend against the use of `git commit -a`: it lets people ignore the index, but only for a little while. It's better to learn to live with Git's index, because sooner or later, Git is going to smash you in the face with it, and if you know it exists and what it does, it won't hurt as much.

Comment: I'll echo @torek's comment a bit - instead of saving kestrokes there, I suggest making aliases for the long command names, e.g., `co` for `checkout`, `ci` (checkin) or `cm` for `commit`, `st` for `status`, `br` for `branch`. I save a lot of keystrokes without losing track of what git is doing for me vs to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `-a` *(automatically add)* option is causing the error.  If you use it with a path on the `git` command, you get errors.

The `-m` option requires an argument, the message, so you either need to make your function manage two arguments or change how you use the function.

To provide a generic git-checkin-with-message function, I'd use something like this:

```sh
gcim() {
  git commit -m "${1:?'Missing git commit message!'}"
}
```

Then use it just like `git commit -m`.  For example:

```sh
gcim "My cool commit does really good stuff"
```

Adding files to the commit is almost always better done *beforehand*.  `git -a` will happily add all files if you happen to use `.` as an argument.  The only thing protecting `git commit -a` from inserting unwanted files is a properly constructed `.gitignore` file.

However, if you sometimes want to do a `git -a -m "some msg"` command, you can make another function:

```sh
gciam() {
  local msg="${1:?Missing commit message!}"
  shift
  if (( $# > 0 )) ; then
    git commit -m "$msg" $*
  else
    echo "Missing files to add!"
  fi
}
```

Then, to use:

```sh
gciam "added new file" that_file.rb
```

Comment: “The -a option is causing the error. If you use it without providing any explicit  filenames or directory names on the git command, you get errors." No, `-a` param of `git commit` don't need a path for argument. The error "fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense." in question shows this too. The root cause of error, pointed out by @torek in comment, is the unquoted $1.

Comment: *The -a option is causing the error. If you use it without providing any explicit filenames or directory names on the git command, you get errors.* Exactly the other way around: it's either `-a` or paths but not both.

Answer (score 0):

[Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) - `$1` is being split into *words* (which have a special meaning in *nix shell scripts). So any words except the first one in your commit message is treated as a filename, which indeed does not make sense with `-a`.